# Searching for an item in an arrayList, comparing it from input and removing it

Tags: java, arraylist

My first question on StackOverflow:

So I have a program that contains a class called items that allows the creation of objects called 'item's... These item objects represent books and contain data based on such (String title, String author, String genre).

For future reference here is the equals method in the item object class:

```
public boolean equals(Item i)
{
    if((i.getTitle()).equals(title)&&(i.getAuthor()).equals(author)&&(i.getType()).equals(title)){
        return true;
    } else {
        return false;        
    }
}
```

In another class called library that reads from a text file and creates an array list of 'Item's, there is a 'remove' method that returns a boolean value depending on whether the item exists in the arrayList or not. Here is the code that I have so far for the remove method:

```
public boolean remove(Item i)
{
   //return false if item is not in the list, call equals method from item class
  if(!items.contains(i)){
     return false;
  } else {

  }
}
```

After validating that the item is in the list, I need to compare the input 'Item i' to the item on the list using the equals method from the Item class but I am not entirely sure how to go about finding the exact object in the list that appears to be equal to 'Item i' and then validating it using the equals method to compare it with 'Item i' before removing it from the list.

Comment: did you mean for the last `.euals(title)` to be `title` instead of `type`?

Comment: you need to loop through the list and check each item in the list to see if it is item `i`, once found, exit the loop and remove it

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You'll need to iterate over all the elements in the list. If the element is found, you remove it and return `true`. If not found, return `false`.

```
public boolean remove(Item i)
{
   //return false if item is not in the list, call equals method from item class
   for(Item current : items){
      if(current.equals(i)){
         items.remove(current);
         return true;
      } 
   }
   return false;
}
```

Comment: Needless code. The [`List::remove`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/10/docs/api/java/util/List.html#remove(java.lang.Object)) method does exactly this.

Answer (score 1):

Something like:

```
if (list.contains(i))
    list.remove(i);
```

Is that what you're going for. Maybe a little more context would help.